# incidence matrix of a mixed graph

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs, adjacency-matrix

I have read about incidence matrix of a mixed graph but without example. All examples I saw were either for undirected graphs or for directed graphs but not for mixed graph.

What will be the incidence matrix of the mixed graph below

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You make $A_{i,j}$ equal the number of edges from $i$ to $j$.

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I will be happy if you can further your explanation. If the adjacency matrix is the one you provided above, then the matrix did not show the direction (-1) for the arc/directed edge from the undirected edge (1)..

Comment: no, you do not use -1. you only use 0 and 1. But the matrix is no longer symmetric.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is the matrix you provided an incidence matrix? I need the incidence matrix of the graph.

Comment: yes it is${}{}{}{}$